# Mysql through PHP gives a "Can't create/write to file" error

Tags: mysql, file-io

The full error is:

> Message: Mysqli statement execute
>   error : Can't create/write to file
>   '/var/www/zendApp/backup/mysql/1268733580_name.sql'
>   (Errcode: 13)

I have tried several things already with the /var/www/ZendApp/backup/mysql directory

```
$chmod 777 mysql
$chmod 1777 mysql
$chown root:root mysql
$chown mysql:mysql mysql
```

But nothing helps. What am I doing wrong here? Do I have to tell mysql somewhere that I can write to that directory?

Comment: Are you creating new file or write to existing one?

Comment: @Dmitry, sorry, didn't see your comment until now. I'm creating a new one. But I just discovered the solution and will put it in an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help off Dominik @ Super User, I discovered that Ubuntu is running apparmor and my server is running on Ubuntu. I quote from wikipedia:

> AppArmor allows the system
>   administrator to associate with each
>   program a security profile that
>   restricts the capabilities of that
>   program

Sure enough, among those programs was mysqld. So not the user or his privileges are the problem, but the restrictions imposed on the process by apparmor. I then found the solution [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/204042)

```
sudo touch /etc/apparmod.d/disable/usr.sbin.mysqld
sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor reload
```

This makes mysqld a free process which for me, on that server, is no problem. So, after days of searching, problem fixed!